# Арифметическая функция на PHP

Tags: php

Нужен такой результат `865` от данных действий `104 - 349`.

Здесь как бы каждое число выступает как десяток.

```
11 - 3 = 8

10 - 4 = 6

14 - 9 = 5
```

Отсюда и получается `865`. Как это сделать на PHP?

Comment: Для начала, вы хотя бы объясните нормально что функция должна делать...

Answer (score 1):

Это очень и очень просто. Сохраняем результат в переменные и конкатинируем их. `.` - [оператор конкатенации](http://hp.net/manual/ru/language.operators.string.php).

```
$one = 11 - 3;
$two = 10 - 4;
$three = 14 - 9;

echo $one . $two . $three;
```

А можно и так:

```
echo (11 - 3) . (10 - 4) . (14 - 9);
```

Оформляем в функцию:

```
function getStr (array $data) :string {
  return ($data[0] - $data[1]) . ($data[2] - $data[3]) . ($data[4] - $data[5]);
}

echo getStr([11, 3, 10, 4, 14,9]);
```